# Агрегации по нескольким полям

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Есть коллекция вида

```
{game:"1", user:"A", score: 23},
{game:"1", user:"B", score: 51},
{game:"1", user:"C", score: 37},
{game:"2", user:"B", score: 44},
{game:"2", user:"C", score: 25}
```

Для каждый игры необходимо получить лучшего игрока и его счёт. Со счетом разобрался - `aggregate([{ $group: {_id: "$game", score: { $max: "$score" }}}])`, а вот как добавить `user`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать  фреймворк агрегации.
Сначало нужно сортировать документ со счетом в порядке убывания используя оператор [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/). После этого нужно сгруппировать
документы с помощью [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) оператор и возвратит первый документ каждой группы, который представляет собой максимальное используя оператор [**`first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) и переменное [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "score": -1 }}, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$game", "best": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }}}
])
```

Результат:

```
{ "_id" : "2", "best" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55e0a768b5b817a476a55e46"), "game" : "2", "user" : "B", "score" : 44 } }
{ "_id" : "1", "best" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55e0a768b5b817a476a55e44"), "game" : "1", "user" : "B", "score" : 51 } }
```

---

Не нужно использовать [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) здесь, потому что это он вызовет **падение производительности**.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {game: "$game", user: "$user"}, score: { $first: "$score"}}},
    {$sort: { score : -1}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id.game", user: {$first:"$_id.user"}, score: {$first: "$score"}}},
    {$project: { _id: 0, game: "$_id", user: "$user", score: "$score" }}
])
```